# how to initialize a svg animation in angular at the moment is displayed on the screen?

Tags: angular, animation, svg

I have animations in svg that i need initialize after display in the viewport, if i use de svg in javascript vanilla this work properly, but if i use angular the animation start in the moment of loading de page and not in the moment of showing in the screen.

I solved it by creating a structural directive that checks if the parent of the image is on the screen, but I would like to have a cleaner solution without adding the directive, since I have to pass information about the image to it to reserve space on the screen as the image is added to the dom after its father appears on the screen.